# How can I fix this loop creating multiple tables

Tags: php, html, api

I`m trying to get the results of $customerid, $customername en $quota in a table using an API. Obviously im very new to this so please be patient with me. I hope someone can explain to me what I have done wrong. I assume theres something wrong with the loop, because the table that is created looks like this:

---

Customername        Usage   Quota

1   Customername1   652 500 GB

2   Customername2   652 50 GB

3   Customername3   652 500 GB

Customername        Usage   Quota

1   Customername1   12  500 GB

2   Customername2   12  50 GB

3   Customername3   12  500 GB

Customername        Usage   Quota

1   Customername1   6   500 GB

2   Customername2   6   50 GB

3   Customername3   6   500 GB

---

While it **shoud** look like this:

Backup usage

Customername        Usage   Quota

1   Customername1   652 500 GB

2   Customername2   12  50 GB

3   Customername3   6   500 GB

```
<div class="col-md-12 main-content">
    <h1>Backup usage</h1>
    <table class="table table-condensed">
    <tbody>

<?php

$customerid = array("id1", "id2", "id3");
$customername = array("Customername1", "Customername2", "Customername3");
$quota = array("500 GB", "50 GB", "500 GB");

$amount = count($customerid);
        
$curl = curl_init();

foreach($customerid as $key => $customer) {
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://backups.com/$customer/usages",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
    "Authorization: Basic 1234567890",
    "Postman-Token: 1234567890",
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ],
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
                
// Decode JSON
$data = json_decode($response, true);
    
$output = "<table>";
$output .= "<tr><td></td><td>Customername</td><td>Usage</td><td>Quota</td></tr>";

for($i=0; $i<$amount; $i++) {
    $output .= "<tr>";
    $output .= "<td>".($i+1)."</td>";
    $output .= "<td>".$customername[$i]."</td>";
    $output .= "<td>".round($data['items'][138]['value']/1073741824)."</td>";
    $output .= "<td>".$quota[$i]."</td>";
    $output .= "</tr>";
}

$output .= "</table>";

echo $output;

?>


<?php
        }
    curl_close($curl);
?>
        
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why u need the for loop. Try it like this

```
<div class="col-md-12 main-content">
    <h1>Backup usage</h1>
    <table class="table table-condensed">
        <tbody>

    <?php

    $customerid = array("id1", "id2", "id3");
    $customername = array("Customername1", "Customername2", "Customername3");
    $quota = array("500 GB", "50 GB", "500 GB");

    $amount = count($customerid);

    $curl = curl_init();

    $output = "<table>";
    $output .= "<tr><td></td><td>Customername</td><td>Usage</td><td>Quota</td></tr>";
    $c = 0;
    foreach ($customerid as $key => $customer) {

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://backups.com/$customer/usages",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
                "Authorization: Basic 1234567890",
                "Postman-Token: 1234567890",
                "cache-control: no-cache"
            ],
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);

        // Decode JSON
        $data = json_decode($response, true);
        $output .= "<tr>";
        $output .= "<td>" . ($c + 1) . "</td>";
        $output .= "<td>" . $customername[$c] . "</td>";
        $output .= "<td>".round($data['items'][138]['value']/1073741824)."</td>";
        $output .= "<td>" . $quota[$c] . "</td>";
        $output .= "</tr>";
        $c++;

        ?>

        <?php
    }
    $output .= "</table>";

    echo $output;
    curl_close($curl);
    ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```